# Set Console App' Tab Icon size

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, console

I have a Console app with a custom Lightning page where I have set the tab icon and name using:

```
 workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                label: a
            });
             workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                 icon: "utility:description",
                 iconAlt: "Description",
             });
```

I am having trouble setting the size of the tab icon to small.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** - use "standard" icons

In case it is helpful for future readers, I was able to find a solution to this.

I was just building out an aura tab and encountered this same issue. While most icons appeared too large for the tab, I found that any icons selected from the "standard" category rendered correctly (in both size and color). The list of "standard" icons can be found [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#standard).

**Code Example with Images**

For example, in the setTabIcon method:

```
 workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
    tabId: focusedTabId,
     icon: "utility:custom_apps",
     iconAlt: "Description",
 });
```

using an icon selection like this will render the icon incorrectly:

```
icon: "utility:custom_apps",
```

[image]

But using a standard icon will render the size and color appropriate for lightning tabs

```
icon: "standard:custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Nice find, what an absolutely terrible API lol

Answer (score 1):

Only 3 parameters - `tabId, icon, iconAlt` are available for setting Icons `setTabIcon` and 2 parameters - `tabId, label` are available for setting label `setTabLabel`. You cannot change any other properties including `size` of icon. That will lead to disruption in the standard lightning experience and so that will not be allowed and not exposed.

Comment: So is there any workaround to make this icon smaller using javascript or maybe apply some css?

Comment: Not possible as they will be in shadow DOM

Comment: We have the same issue. Salesforce should ensure that tab icons are the same size, so I'd say this is salesforce bug. Of course, salesforce support may think differently :) they usually respond with "working as designed"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the same tab icon and replacing 'utility' with 'standard'.

Previous code-
workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
tabId: focusedTabId,
icon: "utility:custom_apps",
iconAlt: "Description",
});

Updated Code-
workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
tabId: focusedTabId,
icon: "standard:custom_apps",
iconAlt: "Description",
});